# Fixed navigation on scroll doesn't work reliable because of CSS overflow-x: hidden

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll

I would like my navbar to be sticky and load a logo-variation when scrolling. So I added a class `scrolling-active` via EventListener to my header, when scrolling and styled it. It worked fine until I added some **CSS to prevent scrolling on x-axis on mobile**.

After adding the CSS the `scrolling-active` is just added from time to time during scrolling. No matter, which site I'm on and even without reloading, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Just scrolling up to the header and giving the scrolling down another chance, can make it work.

The only thing, I could find out until now: **it seems to be an issue with the** `overflow-x: hidden` on the `html` and `body`-tag – which I need to fit the mobile-screen on the device.
I would really appreciate any hints!

**Adding class when scrolling:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var header = document.querySelector('header');

        header.classList.toggle('scrolling-active', window.scrollY > 0);
    });
```

**CSS to prevent scrolling on x-axis on mobile**.

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

That's my header including the navigation (hamburger menu opening an overlay):

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

    <div class="navbar navbar-light">
    
        <div class="float-left">            
            <div class="site-branding">
                <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
            </div>
            <!--Sticky logo-variation -->
            <div class="site-branding-alternative">
                <?php 
                $sticky_logo_url = get_theme_mod( 'sticky_header_logo' );
                if ($sticky_logo_url )?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <?php echo '<img src="'.$sticky_logo_url.'" alt = "logo alt test" class="sticky_logo_class custom-logo">'; ?>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div><!--float-left-->

        <!--Toggler for menu works fine-->
        <div class="menu float-right">
            …               
        </div>

    </div><!--.navbar-->
    

    <!--Overlay – getting WP-menus – works fine-->
    <div class="menu-overlay">
        …
    </div>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

And that's the SASS used for the header and `.scrolling-active`:

```
header {
    background: transparent;
        img.custom-logo {
            width: auto;
            max-height: 56px;
            @media (min-width: 992px) {
                max-height: 72px;
            }
            @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                max-height: 88px;
            }
        }
     }

#masthead {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100; //Make it float above all other elements
    height: 88px; //Gives us a reference point for the final thing
}

/*Navigation on scroll*/
.scrolling-active {
    background: $color_primary_red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    }

.site-branding-alternative {
    display: none;
}

.scrolling-active .site-branding-alternative {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.scrolling-active .site-branding img {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution and would like to share it with you – sounds simple but still took me quite a time to find out…

I just had to remove the `overflow-x: hidden` from the `body` and add a `overflow-wrap: break-word` to prevent the body from being scrollable in y-axis on mobile.

```
html{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

So now both work – the content resizes mobile to screen with and the navigation on scroll works reliable.